# Use ST_startpoint and linear referencing on a self intersecting linestring that includes a road interchange loop ramp

Tags: postgis, qgis-3

I have a linestring (representing a route along roads) that has a self-intersecting loop.  As it has a self-intersecting loop it is not valid as a linestring. But I need it to be a linestring to determine its startpoint and endpoint in PostGIS and to carry out linear referencing for stops along the route.

Any ideas - must I convert to 3D?

Comment: You could try the ST_MakeValid function, which I am guessing would return a MultiPolygon, and then use ST_Dump to split into individual Linestrings. It is a bit hard to tell without seeing some sample data.

Comment: Why is it invalid? I thought linestrings were allowed to be self-intersecting? When I try this in my nearest PostGIS, I get 't' back: SELECT ST_IsValid('LINESTRING(0 0, 2 0, 2 1, 1 1, 1 -1)'::geometry) ;

Comment: @TurePålsson. That is a good point, though, it seems inconsistent that linestrings can intersect, while polygons cannot.

Comment: For polygons, self-intersections cause all sorts of headaches with inside/outside tests.